# how to a way avoide error "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'" in scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, scrapy

```
    start_urls = ['https://github.com/login']

def parse(self, response):
    return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response,formdata={'login': 'xx',
                                            'password': 'xx'},callback=self.after_login)

def after_login(self, response):
    if "authentication failed" in response.body:
       self.logger.info("fail xx %s", response.body)
```

I tried the above code with reference to the document, but the following error occurred.

```
    if "authentication failed" in response.body:
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

It looks like binary file in response.body.
Is there a way to avoid this error?

and I'm Curious that generally, if login fails, whether "authentication failed" is displayed in response.body?

Thank you for reading my question.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use **`response.text`** as it will also return the body but as a `string`. So you won't have to convert the `string you are searching` to bytes object explicitly.

```
if 'authentication failed' in response.text:
   #Do something
```

Answer (score 2):

`response.body` is a `bytes` value, but `"authentication failed"` is a `str`. You can't mix the types.

Use a `bytes` literal:

```
if b"authentication failed" in response.body:
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply.
I solved it without error.